# Use ListView control to display data but join a reference table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, listview

I'm really new to ASP.NET and I've looked at countless tutorials trying to figure this out but can't seem to get my head around it. I can successfully output records from tbProject using ListView and the Entity Framework but instead of the refDepartmentID, I want to display refDepartmentValue from the refDepartment table. Here is a quick table structure.

```
tbProject
-ProjectID
-refDepartmentID
-ProjectName

refDepartment
-refDepartmentID
-refDeparmentValue
```

I can write this in SQL no problem with a JOIN but I don't know where I'd put it. I've played around with LINQ a bit and it seems like this is how I'm going to accomplish this. Maybe write the LINQ in the code behind file then bind it to the ListView control, maybe?

Here's the ListView control:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">



  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="ProjectIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="refDepartmentIDLabel" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("refDepartmentID") %>' />
      </td>

    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <LayoutTemplate>
   <table runat="server">
     <tr runat="server">
       <td runat="server">
         <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
           <tr runat="server" style="">
             <th runat="server">
               ProjectID</th>
             <th runat="server">
               refDepartmentID</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr runat="server">
        <td runat="server" style="">
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
```

Here's how I'm using the EF to populate a dropdownlist so you can at least refer to how things are named.

```
// populates Departments dropdownlist
using (dbOrganizationEntities1 myEntities = new dbOrganizationEntities1())
{
    var allDepartments = from refDepartments in myEntities.refDepartments
                         select refDepartments;
    ddlDepartments.DataSource = allDepartments;
    ddlDepartments.DataValueField = "refDepartmentID";
    ddlDepartments.DataTextField = "refDepartmentValue";
    ddlDepartments.DataBind();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer, I did this in my head without Visual Studio, so it might have a minor syntax error. Let me know if it does.

You need to do two things, First you must join your tbProject to refDepartments Entites using an inner (or outer) join as needed, depending on your desired behavior. One you have the two tables joined in LINQ, you want to create a new *anonymous class* using "select new" operator which creates it. The members of this new class will be created based on the datatypes of the Entities they are selected from.

```
using (dbOrganizationEntities1 myEntities = new dbOrganizationEntities1())
{
    var allDepartments = (from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects
                            // inner join to department lookup table
                            from refDepartments in myEntities.refDepartments.Where(x=>x.refDepartmentID == tbProject.refDepartmentID) // to do a left join instead of an inner, append .DefaultIfEmpty() after this where clause
                            // select new anon type
                            select new {
                                refDepartmentID = tbProject.refDepartmentID,
                                ProjectName = tbProject.ProjectName,
                                refDepartmentValue = refDepartments.refDepartmentValue,
                            }).ToList(); // I chose to turn the result into a list to demonstrate something below, you can leave it as an enumerable.


    // you can access the properties of the anon type like so
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(allDepartments[0].refDepartmentID);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(allDepartments[0].refDepartmentValue);

    // bind to your listview, make sure control name is accurate and ItemTemplates are defined for each data column.
    MyListView.DataSource = allDepartments;
    MyListView.DataBind();
}
```